# Python Socket Declaration on Server and Client

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a question on socket programming..

Once you import socket on server side ...

```
import socket
serv = socket.socket()
serv.bind(('127.0.0.0', 8080))
serv.listen(5)
conn, addr = serv.accept()
conn.send("Data")
```

why can't I use serv.send() instead of conn.send()?

In client side once I declare, I can use s.send()

```
s = socket.socket()
s.send("Data sent")
```

Comment: Because `serv` isn't connected to anything.

Answer (score -1):

The "client" socket is necessarily connected to a single remote, so it's unambiguous what to send to.

A "server" socket can be connected to by any number of clients, so you need a representation of who any specific client is. That's what `conn` is (it's also a socket, just one connected to a client rather than one waiting for connections).

Comment: A 'server' socket isn't connected to *any* clients.